# How to delete the 0's before the number if the number does not require them?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a program that prints all possible mixtures of numbers from 0 to 9 and I want to delete the numbers that my code puts before the actual number if the output is less than 6 places.

I've tried putting "" before 0 in every array, but it also puts random spaces in the output.

```
Class1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
Class2 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
Class3 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
Class4 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
Class5 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
Class6 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

for i in Class1:
    for j in Class2:
        for k in Class3:
            for l in Class4:
                for m in Class5:
                    for n in Class6:
                        print (i,j,k,l,m,n)
```

So I want it to output lets say 895 and not 000895. It does that until it reaches 100000, but that's logical.

Comment: What's wrong with `for i in range(1000000): print(i)`?

Comment: Why do you need 6 lists with the same content? you can iterate the same list multiple times ...  your output would also add a space betwen each digit ... it would be simpler to do print over a range - if you need digits use a `for i in range(1000000): print(*str(i))` - to get rid of spaces simply `print(i)` - or use `print(str(i´, sep="---")` to place --- between digits

Comment: `print '\n'.join(map(str, range(1000000)))` is cool nope ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
print (i,j,k,l,m,n)
```

By:

```
print (100000*i+10000*j+1000*k+100*l+10*m+n)
```

Answer (score 2):

Although the following code helps you with a similar approach you took in your question I would suggest another way of achieving what you want:

```
Class1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
Class2 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
Class3 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
Class4 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
Class5 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
Class6 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

for i in Class1:
    for j in Class2:
        for k in Class3:
            for l in Class4:
                for m in Class5:
                    for n in Class6:
                        print(int(''.join([str(i),str(j),str(k),str(l),str(m),str(n)])))
```

The above method is using the trick of converting individual numbers to strings, concatenating them with `join()` string method and re-converting them to `int`. With this,a string like `'0000001'` will be converted to `1`.

But a better way is to utilise [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) with the same trick:

```
import itertools
for seq in itertools.product([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], repeat=6):
    print(int(''.join([str(s) for s in seq])))
```

Here inside `join()` I used [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for brevity.

Comment: This works fine but all solutions I got are a bit slower than my code. I wonder if it could be solved using multithreading and if yes, how could it be done

Comment: Note that printing 10^6 numbers is time-consuming. In case of parallelising `multiprocessing` might be a better choice rather than multithreading. In that case I think defining 10 processes assigning each of them one number as the last digit of its output like `xxxxxx1`, `xxxxxx2`, ... will solve your problem.